# How to get event control from another aspx Page. button click or Page load | ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

### 1st Page.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return" />
```

Actually, I need to call this page from another 2nd.aspx.cs page.

```
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
        //Do some stuff in the page load event handler.
    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //Do some stuff in the button click event handler.
    }
```

I change the button Access Modifiers property to public from the designer page.

```
    public global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;
```

### 2nd Page

Create an Object in this page to access 1st page.

```
FirstPageName firstPage = new FirstPageName();
firstPage.Button1_Click();
```

This doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1st Page.

*FirstPageName.aspx* page.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return" />
```

*FirstPageName.aspx.cs* page.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //Do some stuff in the button click event handler.
}
```

Change the button Access Modifiers property to **public** from the designer page.

```
public global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;
```

### 2nd Page

Here, we can use 2 methods.

- **1st Method**

Create an Object in this page to access 1st page.

```
FirstPageName firstPage = new FirstPageName();
firstPage.Button1_Click(firstPage.Button1, EventArgs.Empty);
```

- **2nd Method**

Create an Object in this page to access 1st page.

```
FirstPageName firstPage = new FirstPageName();
firstPage.Button1.Click += new EventHandler(firstPage.Button1_Click);
```

- **I'm also attaching another two methods. Try this, This works for me.**

  `YourButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));`

  `Button.PerformClick();`

Comment: If any doubts, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.8